# Change inline onkeyup function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following textarea:

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="4" id="textbox" onkeyup="limitArea(this, 255, '')"></textarea>
```

What i need it the `onkeyup` function to instead read `onkeyup="limitArea(this, 150, '')"` -- the problem is, I can't edit this part of the code directly.

I tried this with no success:

```
$('textarea[onkeyup="limitArea(this, 255, \'\')"]').attr('onkeyup', 'limitArea(this, 255, \'\')');
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: I noticed your textarea has an ID...why not select it with `$("#textbox")`

Comment: The jQuery works, but I must be going blind, cause it does'nt look like you are changing anything to me? The inline handler is exactly the same both places. See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPjJS/5/), and inspect the elements, and you'll see it's changed !

Comment: `$("#textbox").on('keyup', ...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually change something, and not just give it the same value :

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea[onkeyup="limitArea(this, 255, \'\')"]')
                .attr('onkeyup', 'limitArea(this, 150, \'\')');
});                                     //changed ^^^^
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPjJS/5/)

As ID's are unique, it would be a lot easier to target the element with the ID:

```
$('#textbox')
```

Comment: Oddly enough, in the code I was playing with it wasn't working and it was the same as yours (I thought -- and yes, I had 150 in mine). But, I posted this, came back, and tried again with yours and lo and behold it starts working. But, oh well, working code is working code. Thanks!